# Swift: Where can I find a list of all the forkey arguments available for Alert actions

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

```
//this is the cancel button code

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: 
UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)})

cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.white(), forKey: "titleTextColor")
cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.equiaviaBlue(), forKey: "backgroundColor")
```

.....but there is no backgroundColor `forKey`.
Does anyone know where I can find a list of arguments for the `forKey` variable?

Comment: Don't use `UIAlertController` if its public API doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, the `titleTextColor` property does not seem to be documented anywhere, which would mean that setting it in this manner probably constitutes private API usage and may get your app banned from the App Store. It also may cause your app to break if the internal implementation of `UIAlertAction` changes in the future. In addition, inspecting the UIKit binary with class-dump, there doesn't seem to be any obvious property corresponding to the background color. Therefore, it's probably not possible to do what you're trying to do, and it wouldn't be advisable anyway if it were.